# COUNT LIKE to find a string

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

In Oracle. I want to count the number of times each string appears. Taking as reference 4/10, 4/11, 4/8.

| STRING |
| --- |
| Upstream Channel 4/10.0/0 |
| Upstream Channel 4/10.1/0 |
| Upstream Channel 4/11.0/0 |
| Upstream Channel 4/11.1/0 |
| Upstream Channel 4/8.0/0 |
| Upstream Channel 4/8.1/0 |
| Upstream Channel 4/8.2/0 |
| Upstream Channel 4/8.3/0 |

| STRING | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| Upstream Channel %4/10.% | 2 |
| Upstream Channel %4/11.% | 2 |
| Upstream Channel %4/8.% | 4 |

Comment: Your results include the prefix string.  However, your problem is only focused on the number expressions.  That makes the question unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is exact requirement. But you can use the `substr` and `instr` with `count` as follows:

```
select substr(str, 1, instr(str,'.')) as str_trunc,
       count(*) as occurance
  from your_Table t
 group by substr(str, 1, instr(str,'.'))
```

If you just want to find the count of `4/10, 4/11 and 4/8` then you can use the like as follows:

```
select temp.str, count(*)
  from (select '4/10' as val, 'Upstream Channel %4/10.%' as str from dual
        union all select '4/11' as val, 'Upstream Channel %4/11.%' as str from dual
        union all select '4/18' as val, 'Upstream Channel %4/8.%' as str from dual
       ) temp
  left join your_table t on t.str like '%' || temp.val || '%'
 group by temp.str
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here to isolate the two number versions:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\s(\d+/\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS STRING,
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '\s(\d+/\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo